# Train spaCy NER model from Python script (not CLI)

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai, spacy-3

I am aware that training a spaCy model (say, Named Entity Recognition), requires [running some commands from CLI](https://spacy.io/usage/training#quickstart). However, because I need to train a spaCy model inside a [Vertex AI Pipeline Component](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/pipelines/lightweight_functions_component_io_kfp.ipynb) (which can be simply considered as a *"Pure Python script"*), training a spaCy model from CLI IS NOT an option for my use case. My current attempt looks like this:

```py
#train.py
# IMPORTANT: Assume all the necessary files are already available in the same directory than this script

import spacy
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "spacy", "init", "fill-config", "base_config.cfg", "config.cfg"])

subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "spacy", "train", "config.cfg",
                "--output", "my_model",
                "--paths.train", "train.spacy",
                "--paths.dev", "dev.spacy"])
```

Which allows me to carry-on with the training (however not being quite stable at times). But I don't know if this is the best implementation, or there is something better or more recommended (once again, NOT involving CLI).

**IMPORTANT:** As a Python script, if I run it via `python train.py`, it should run without a problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: `spacy` is python module and you could check source code to see how it runs `init` and `train` - and you could use it directly in your script without using `subprocess.run`. You can find source code using `print( spacy.__file__ )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have a functional solution now:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from spacy.cli.download import download
from spacy.cli.init_config import fill_config
from spacy.cli.train import train

download('en_core_web_lg')
fill_config(Path("config.cfg"), Path("base_config.cfg"))
train(Path("config.cfg"), Path("my_model"), overrides={"paths.train": "train.spacy", "paths.dev": "dev.spacy"})
```

With it, I have managed to successfully train a spaCy NER model, from a Python script (i.e., via `python train.py`).

For more details, please check [this thread](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/11673).

Thanks.

Comment: you could mark your answer as accepted. And you could also add [link to documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/training#api-train) which you get in [your thread](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/11673)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it resolve all problems but ...

... you can find path to source code (see  `print( spacy.__file__ )` ) and you can check code in `__main__.py`. It imports code from `spacy.cli` and it loads code from other files in folder `spacy/cli/`

**EDIT:** you can also see source code on github: [spacy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy)

**EDIT:** I correct `string path` to `Path()`

For example:

```
from spacy.cli.download import download

download('en_core_web_sm')
```

```
from spacy.cli.info import info

print(info())
```

```
from spacy.cli.init_config import fill_config
from pathlib import Path

#fill_config("config.cfg", "base_config.cfg")  # different order
fill_config(Path("config.cfg"), Path("base_config.cfg"))  # different order
```

```
from spacy.cli.train import train
from pathlib import Path

#train("config.cfg", "my_model")
train(Path("config.cfg"), Path("my_model"))
```

But you may also try:

```
from spacy.cli import setup_cli
import sys

sys.argv = ['spacy', '--help']
setup_cli()
```

```
from spacy.cli import setup_cli
import sys

sys.argv = ['spacy', 'train']
setup_cli()
```

But it seems this method may hang when it can't get arguments.

Comment: Hello @furas . Please notice that `fill_config` require arguments to be of `pathlib.Path` type. I have come up with a solution by now, thanks.